# Internal stylesheet not working in IE9 with jsf

Tags: css, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using jsf2.0 with primefaces.My application was working fine with all browsers includes IE8... but when i run my application in IE9 my internal stylesheet not even taken by browser(IE9).. The styles are broken.

my css on head:

```
<h:head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" />

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Chennai Volunteers</title>
<link href="cv_website_styles.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
<script charset="utf-8" src="http://widgets.twimg.com/j/2/widget.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
</h:head>
```

and i am getting the follwing error in my console,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ContentTypeList does not contain a supported content type: text/css
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.selectContentType(HtmlRendererUtils.java:1905)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(HtmlRenderKitImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:154)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I checked your website chennaivolunteers.org and I noticed that `FacesServlet` is been mapped on an URL pattern of `/faces/*` instead of `*.xhtml`. As you're using only relative `<link>` and `<script>` resource references, they will (unnecessarily) go through the `FacesServlet` as well.

IE9 sends for CSS files a `Accept-Header` of `text/css` while other browsers sends a `Accept-Header` of `text/css;*/*`. The `FacesServlet` itself is not supposed to respond on `text/css` requests.

There are basically 2 ways to fix this:

- Get rid of the `/faces/*` mapping and replace it by `*.xhtml`.

  ```
  <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  ```
- Use domain-relative URLs in `<link>` and `<script>` (and `<img>`) references so that they never go through the `/faces` path.

  ```
  <ui:param name="root" value="#{request.contextPath}/" />
  <link href="#{root}cv_website_styles.css" rel="stylesheet"  type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="#{root}css/style.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="#{root}js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="#{root}js/script.js"></script>
  ```

  Or use the `<base>` tag, or use `<h:outputStylesheet>` and `<h:outputScript>` with a `name` instead.

Your site has by the way quite some 404's on several resources. Fix that as well. Check the "Net", "Network" section of the browser's builtin web developer toolset (press F12 in IE9/Chrome/Firebug).

Comment: Balusc,your great.. Exactly, that is the mistake we made... thanks

Comment: This was only part of the solution in my case since my application is using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces 3.3.x. [This](http://technology-for-human.blogspot.com/2011/12/jsf-12-myfaces-richfaces-33x-ie-9.html) worked for the most parts.