# JSF Content Type List not supported text/css with IE 9 and above browser issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, jsf, internet-explorer-10, jsf-1.2

I am using **JSF 1.2** and my application is working fine with **IE 8** and below version browser and recently upgraded to **IE 10** browser. Now the entire site looks broken. And it's throwing following exception in tomcat error log.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ContentTypeList does not contain a supported content type:      text/css
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.renderkit.html.HtmlRendererUtils.selectContentType(HtmlRendererUtils.java:1905)
at org.apache.myfaces.renderkit.html.HtmlRenderKitImpl.createResponseWriter(HtmlRenderKitImpl.java:223)
at org.apache.myfaces.shared_impl.view.JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.renderView(JspViewDeclarationLanguageBase.java:154)
at org.apache.myfaces.application.ViewHandlerImpl.renderView(ViewHandlerImpl.java:263)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.RenderResponseExecutor.execute(RenderResponseExecutor.java:85)
at org.apache.myfaces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:239)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:191)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:185)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:151)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:269)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

As per below link suggestion:

[CSS Style sheet not working with IE 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11158306/internal-stylesheet-not-working-in-ie9-with-jsf/)

I changed code now site looks fine. But it's end with new problem. Now the site looks like normal as before but caching problem is happening.For example If we select one item from selectManyListbox it stays permanently there. After that whatever I selected it showing that old value only.

Let me know if you need any other information regarding this.Thanks is advance.

Comment: We will need a repro demo, or access to the site itself.

Comment: Hi @Jonathan Sampson it's secured application so I am not able to share the site information. But I can able to share some code like web.xml.. if needed.

Comment: Can you create a small repro that shows the issue?

Comment: Thanks. I will create and let you know as soon as possible.